# Some very basic questions on "change", "rate", and "rate of change".

Tags: calculus

Let $f:[x_1, x_2]\to\Bbb R$ be a function, and let $y = f(x)$. The *average rate of change of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$ over the interval $[x_1, x_2]$* is **defined** as the quotient
$$
\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1},
$$
where $\Delta x = x_2 - x_1$ and $\Delta y = f(x_2) - f(x_1)$.

And the *rate of change of $f(x)$ at a point* is **defined** as the limit of the average rates of changes as $\Delta x \to 0$.

$(1)$ What *is* **change** in mathematics? It seems that the concept of change requires the concept of *time*, which I think doesn't exist in mathematics. I think only physical variables make sense of change. For instance, elapsed time, distanced traveled, temperature, etc. Thus, it also makes sense that mathematical functions when they model the physical variables *can* change. But I don't think it makes sense otherwise until we are extending the concept of change. What is happening here?

$(2)$ What exactly is **rate**? Intuitively, it is something that describes how fast or slow a quantity is changing with respect to another quantity. But intuitive notions are formally defined in mathematics, that is, using symbols and formulae, so it can be manipulated. The formal definition, when deciphered, completely reflects the original intuitive notion. Rate of change of $y$ with respect to $x$ is defined as the quotient $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$. (Not exactly, it is the *average* rate of change.) How did mathematicians realize that $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ does reflect the intuitive notion completely? Where can I find a rigorous discussion on this issue?

$(3)$ Average rate of change is defined before the instantaneous rate of change. But you need instantaneous rate of change and integration to know that average rate of change over an interval really is the *average* of the instantaneous rates of changes over the interval. Then, is it not circular reasoning? I don't think it is *if* the logic is as follows: The quantity $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ exists. It pops up every now and then throughout mathematics and the physical sciences. So, it's only natural to give it a name. Like everything it can be named whatever we please. For example, it could've been named *banana*. But we are going to name it the *average rate of change of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$ over the interval $[x_1,x_2]$*. Returning to the issue, if indeed it is the logic behind the naming, did mathematicians change its name to include "average" *after* they had come to realize that it really is the average of the rates of changes?

Answer (score 1):

First off, it's bad practice to ask more than one question at a time, in a post. I'm going to address your first questions. The other ones should be asked elsewhere, if they need to be.

> 1. What is change in mathematics?

Change is generally taken to be the [*difference*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Difference.html) between two values, $\Delta x=x_1-x_0$, as is the case when considering rates of change and derivatives. We might, at other times, consider change as the *absolute difference*, $|x_1-x_0|$, irrespective of sign. More generally than that, we might define change in terms of a [*metric*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Metric.html), a function that conforms to certain rules and assigns value to pairs of elements, which can be interpreted as their distance from one another, in some sense.

> It seems that the concept of change requires the concept of time, which I think doesn't exist in mathematics.

Change doesn't require temporality (time) at all. Any two [*real numbers*](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RealNumber.html) have a well-defined difference, be that $3-4=-1$ or $2.7-0.3=2.4$. All we need for that is the ability to subtract. More generally, a metric can be defined for elements in any set. While a *rate* requires some sense of dependency between two variables (e.g. $x$ vs. $y$), change needs only one variable (e.g. $x$).

As to whether time is studied in math, it's simply not in the scope of the field; time is an object of study of physics. The objects of study of math might *be derived from*, or *be designed to describe*, or be *understood through the lens of* physical phenomena, and there is a huge degree of overlap there, but math is essentially uninterested in natural or physical phenomena themselves, including time. Instead, math tends to investigate purely abstract objects, such as the real numbers, which we may use to describe time in physics.

> What exactly is rate?

You've defined it correctly as the quotient. I don't see why you're asking this.

> How did mathematicians came [sic] to be sure that this quotient does reflect the intuitive notion completely? Where is this issue discussed rigorously?

Concepts of ratios, proportionality between values, and (non-instantaneous) speed are prehistoric and were used extensively by ancient cultures. Remarking that a plank of wood measures $3$ times the length of another, or that a pack of people can walk $2$ miles in a day *are both* applications of an implicit concept of rate and speed. And Euclid, for instance, made extensive use of ratios in their work on geometry. See this article on the use of ratios in Ancient Greek math, [D. H. Fowler, *Ratio in Early Greek Mathematics* (1979)](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1979-01-06/S0273-0979-1979-14684-6/S0273-0979-1979-14684-6.pdf).

The modern notion of the rate of change of a function, or the instantaneous rate of change (derivative) required development of the function concept, which arose in 17th c. Europe. See this overview of the history of the function concept, [João Pedro Ponte, *The History of the Concept of Function*](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/12423242.pdf).

As to whether the mathematical description reflects the intuitive notion, that is a question for philosophy and does not suggest a straightforward answer. I think it's far from obvious what the intuitive notion of a rate is, and it's certainly not easy to untangle how mathematical objects relate to mental concepts.